# How to decrypt OpenPGP file using data flow component without saving the file to disk?

Tags: sql, ssis

I was wondering if anyone knows of a data flow source component in SSIS (free or pay) that will decrypt an OpenPGP file on the fly (keep it all in memory) and output it through to the source.

I've seen tasks (control flow components) that do this but I don't want the OpenPGP
file to ever be written to disk in a decrypted state.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up comments.  Good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CozyRoc has a tool.  I am not sure if it encrypts/decrypts in memory, but I have never noticed a temp file on disk.

See the [CozyRoc OpenPGP Sample](http://cozyroc.com/ssis/openpgp-task) at the bottom of the linked page.  It seems to indicate that you can do what you want.

Comment: Curse you and your speedy response ;)  There's a codeplex page for the [Community Tasks and Components](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/). I see CozyRoc listed on there but it's a Control Flow component as opposed to a data flow task. To keep in memory, you are probably looking at a script source and using the libraries. Hopefully they are strongly signed and you can get them pushed into the GAC.

Comment: Sorry @billinkc, I have the advantage of having the CozyRoc suite in house and I do use the PGP encryption task, however I have never needed to go to the level of not writing intermediate files to disk.

Comment: I was thinking of making a script source (looks like bouncy castle is strong signed) that would keep it all in memory. I haven't actually used the CozyRoc component but since it is a task in a control flow I was thinking it is going to decrypt to a file. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ahhh, I see the link of how to run it without intermediate storage. I'll take a look at that but that looks like what i want. Thanks

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I successfully implemented this solution without ever writing to disk by using the cozyroc component to write the (bouncycastle) stream to a variable and using a data source script component to write the decrypted data to an ssis stream and it worked perfectly. Side Note: Task Factory doesn't have this ability but they did add it as a feature request. The stream should take care of any memory issues because it should only buffer as much as it can handle at least thats what i see when I import a 500 mb file into it and only see 50mb being used in memory.